# What is the difference between a repeated cross-sectional survey design and a trend survey design?

Tags: repeated-measures, survey, methodology, survey-sampling, cross-section

Most of the references I have checked for repeated cross-sectional design and trend design (a type of longitudinal design) have said that they are one and the same. However, my professor says that there is a difference between the two but would not tell us the difference. He gave a clue that it had something to do with external validity but I can't seem to draw the connection between them all.

In a given reading about the two designs, there appears to only be one difference between the two:

> Where different respondents are studied at one or more different points in time, the study is called ‘cross-sectional’, i.e. a cross- section of the population is taken to investigate the topic(s) of interest. Where a few selected factors are studied continuously over time, the term ‘trend study’ is employed (Cohen et al., 2017).

Though I'm not really sure if this answer would suffice. I really just want to know what could be the main difference between them. Just in case this becomes important, the course is about Quantitative Research Methods and this topic is under Survey Design.

Reference: Cohen, L., Manion, L., & Morrison, K. R. B. (2017). Research methods in education.

Comment: In marketing research, the more common usage is *continuous tracking surveys*, not *trend surveys*.

Comment: @MikeHunter Thanks for the input! Would look into that. I would just like to say that I don't really have a specific field in mind for this as we are simply discussing research as it exists in all disciplines.

Comment: Imo, your professor 's seeming unwillingness to explain the distinction is evidence for ignorance of same https://www.iwh.on.ca/what-researchers-mean-by/cross-sectional-vs-longitudinal-studies There are more important issues at stake here, e.g., the questions concerning the challenges of inferring causality using any type of noninterventional observational survey vs interventional random controlled trials (RCTs). Here the controversies passionately swirl around on both sides. See Deaton, https://medium.com/@timothyogden/experimental-conversations-angus-deaton-b2f768dffd57#.an25s7r69

Comment: One more thing wrt optimization. Krumme's new book is a cautionary tale about the pitfalls of same https://www.google.com/books/edition/Optimal_Illusions/j9erEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: @MikeHunter My professor seems to have a very specific answer in mind which he says we need to find out ourselves, so Idk really. I agree though, there really are other more important issues than the definitions of these terms. I appreciate all these references you gave though I think that's way beyond the scope of the course haha I'm still an undergrad and this is my first research course, so I kind of don't have a good grasp of the basics (yet, hopefully). Still, thanks a lot!